# Ошибка в SQL коде

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, mysql-workbench

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT (idSubscriber) 
    FROM (
        (SELECT idPlan, Communication_idCommunication
            FROM Plan
                WHERE Communication_idCommunication = 3 ) AS A
                INNER JOIN
                ( SELECT *
                    FROM Subscriptions) AS B ON A.idPlan = B.idPlan)
```

Вывод: ошибка:

```
1630 FUNCTION mylab.COUNT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual  0.000 sec.
```

Что она значит?

Comment: у вас пробел которого быть не должно, между COUNT и скобкой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT idSubscriber)
FROM (
  SELECT idPlan, Communication_idCommunication
  FROM Plan
  WHERE Communication_idCommunication = 3 
) AS A
INNER JOIN Subscriptions AS B ON A.idPlan = B.idPlan;
```

Проблема в пробеле между `COUNT` и `(DISTINCT...`